# How to get Json response by selenium webdriver using Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to get Json response by selenium webdriver. How to get it as a Json format. Currently what I get is a String format.

Here is what I'm trying to get:
{"id":377,"text":"Playing Sudoku is fun!"}

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"id":377,"text":"Playing Sudoku is fun!"}</pre>
```

Here is my code:

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class GameTestSelenuim {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/lulu/Desktop/Selenium/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/game");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("pre")).getText();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium getText() method always returns a string value. You can convert the json string value to JSON object using any JSON library.

Here I used [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/lulu/Desktop/Selenium/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/game");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("pre")).getText();
    System.out.println(text);
    JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(text);
    System.out.println(jsonobject.getString("text"));
    System.out.println(jsonobject.getInt("id"));
}
```

**JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(text)** - Here we create JSON object.