# Read JSON response when selenium clicks on a button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am currently working on learning selenium and my current requirement is to read an API JSON response when a certain button inside my application UI is clicked. 
I mainly use Java and selenium but I have the flexibility in using any other language.

The click triggers an event which hits an API and a response is received. Hitting the API directly without going through the UI is not an option. 
Additionally, when using Developer Tools in chrome, i can see the response in the "Network" tab. If there is any way that i could just read the "Network" tab, that is also acceptable.

Comment: Didn't tried but looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270471/how-to-get-json-response-by-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: it is most unlikely that selenium can read anything from 'network' tab. is your application storing API response into any element ?

Comment: Currently i am unable to store the API response as the API is not being called in the Java code. The button click triggers a call to the API which in turn needs to be stored. That is the tricky part. The code doesn't interact with the API directly.

Comment: @UjjwalMaheshwari I mean what is the activity UI button click trigger does after it received JSOn response?

Comment: Take a look at browsermobproxy or performance API, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46936851/how-to-access-the-values-of-chromes-dev-tools-network-tabs-request-or-summary/46939621#46939621

Comment: Actually I recommend looking at chromium network api or monkey-patching xhr.

Comment: @Melan the response consists of data that is used to plot tiles on a map. The link is a snippet of the network tab of the response received https://ibb.co/smzmdX2